# Angular 7 - Comparar Listas

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Eu tenho duas listas no meu componente.

```
listPermissoesOfUser: UsuarioPermissoes[];
listAnotherPermissoes: UsuarioPermissoes[];
```

E quando eu carrego a pagina, eu exibo elas em um picklist do primeNG (Dois containers). Só que quando eu carrego, eu preciso comprar as duas listas, o que tiver na **listPermissoesOfUser** não pode aparecer na **listAnotherPermissoes**

A função que carrega as informações da página está abaixo:

```js
loadPage() {
    this.idUser = this.route.snapshot.params.id;

    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap(params => this.usuarioPermissoesService.getPermissoesOfUser(+params.get("id")))
    ).subscribe(
      (listPermissoesOfUser: UsuarioPermissoes[]) => {this.listPermissoesOfUser = listPermissoesOfUser; },
      (error) => {console.log(error); }
    );
    this.usuarioPermissoesService.getListFuncionalidades().subscribe(
      (listAnotherPermissoes: UsuarioPermissoes[]) => {this.listAnotherPermissoes = listAnotherPermissoes},
      (error) => {console.log(error); }
    );
    //Funcionalidades que o usuario tem, não aparece na listAnotherPermissoes

  }
```

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Não é melhor isso já vir pronto no retorno, ou seja, da onde vem essas informações? não seria de lá, fiz formatada todas as informações.

Comment: Você quer dizer no banco de dados? Qual seria o comando para um `SELECT` que faça uma busca e não retorne as linhas em comum com o "**id_usuario**"?

Comment: Então o seu problema não é ai e sua pergunta acaba sendo outra ...

Comment: Eu perguntei isso porcausa que já tentei fazer isso no banco de dados, e a consulta não dá certo por causa das poucas Fk's nas tabelas. Já tentei usar LEFT JOIN, Where IS NOT, <> entre outros, ma snenhum atende ao que preciso, por isso acho mais fácil tentar fazer no Angular ou, talvez, no PHP.

Comment: Olha se esse pesquisa não está dando certa se deve ter problemas no seu back end e ai fica complicado dizer qualquer coisa.

Comment: Eu tenho dois SELECT's no DB, um deles busca as permissões do usuário; a outra busca todas as permissões. No segundo SELECT, eu teria que fazer uma busca que, por causa da maneira como está ligada as tabelas, não teria com fazer em uma consulta, teria que fazer duas consultas separadas e trazer o resultado delas, mas se eu fizer isso, teria que fazer no PHP. Fazer no PHP ou no Angular daria no mesmo.

Comment: Se quiser, posso postar as tabelas pra vocês analisarem melhor a situação.

Comment: Tem que ser em outra pergunta, porque, ficaria duas perguntas.

Comment: Criei outra pergunta: [MySql - Comparar duas listas e filtrar informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380092/mysql-comparar-duas-listas-e-filtrar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer assim:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = [3,4,6];
x.filter(x => y.find(y => y == x)); // [3]
```

Ele vai resultar em um array composto pelas duplicatas, assim você pode remover estes na lista de todas permissões.

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = [3,4,6];
x.filter(x => y.indexOf(x) < 0); // [1,2]
```