# MySql/PHP - Comparar duas listas e filtrar informações

Tags: php, mysql, select

Essa é uma questão de ENEM (brincadeiras a parte, vamos a dúvida).
A resposta pode ser em **MySQL** ou em **PHP**.

Eu preciso fazer uma busca onde eu liste todas as permissões que o usuário não possui. Para isso eu tenho a seguintes tabelas:

sys_perfil_permissoes

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_perfil_permissoes` (
    `id_perfil_permissao` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_perfil` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_funcionalidade` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `permissao` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_perfil_permissao`)
)
```

sys_usuario_permissoes

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_usuario_permissoes` (
    `id_usuario_permissao` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_usuario` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_perfil_permissao` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `permissao` INT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario_permissao`)
)
```

A tabela sys_perfil_permissoes funciona como um *default*, quando cria um usuário, ele já tem algumas permissões por *default*, quando eu salvo essas permisões do usuário, elas ficam salvas na tabela sys_usuario_permissoes.

Como posso buscar as permissões que o usuário não tem em um SELECT?

Na tela, ficaria assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize no `SELECT` o método `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` passando outro `SELECT` dentro com as condições. Exemplo:

```
SELECT 
   t.id
FROM 
   teste as t                      
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM permissoes as p
    WHERE 
      p.teste_id = t.id);
```

Então o resultado será todos que não existirem na tabela ali que usei de exemplo.

Comment: Então vou ter que fazer um select da mesma tabela?

Comment: Ou ficaria assim?
SELECT * FROM sys_perfil_permissoes pp
JOIN sys_funcionalidades f ON pp.id_funcionalidade = f.id_funcionalidade
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys_usuario_permissoes up2 WHERE up2.id_funcionalidade = pp.id_funcionalidade
AND up2.id_usuario = 660 )